# CSS for two boxes with dynamic size on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes (or you may call them *columns*) on the same line.

Both have **dynamic widths**, and they must be on the same line (or *row*).

Let me elaborate:

```
.----------container 570px-----------.
|[box1]                        [box2]|  The perfect situation
|                                    |
|[box1box1box1box1box1box1box1][box2]|  A nice situation
|                                    |
|[box1box1box1box1box1box1box1]      |  But when [box1] and [box2] are too big,
|              [box2box2box2box2box2]|  [box2] breaks to a new line
|                                    |
|[box1box1b...][box2box2box2box2box2]|  I need [box1] to get ellipsed
|____________________________________|
```

Is there a way to achieve this only with CSS? Because with Javascript, I can just take the size of **box2** and set a new `width` of **box1**.

You you have a CSS rule that works for IE9, that's totally cool.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible with CSS.

Comment: It's an option the use of max-width?

Comment: Browsers developers should give us `:overflow` pseudo-class.  Then, it is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like sass that allow you to set variables inside the stylesheet, but that would be just as easy as using javascript. I'm afraid there is no way to make this calculation in css.
My only suggestion would be to set a `max-width` on both divs to ensure that the other div has its own space.

Answer (score 0):

To replace elements in single row declare them as table-cell:

Markup:

```
<div class=horizontal>
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.horizontal > * {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QYq2R/

Comment: Unfortunately this does not do what the OP asked for - if the combined text from both `div`s exceeds the width of the parent they overflow. He wants the text to be truncated with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dynamic styling based on the size of content is outside the scope of CSS; you would need some cunning jQuery to do this I think. Here is the approach I would take:

```
function SetWidths() {
    var TotalWidth = $('#Box1').OuterWidth() + $('#Box2').OuterWidth();
    var ContainerWidth = $('#Container').InnerWidth();

    if (TotalWidth > ContainerWidth)
        //truncate the width of Box1 if that is the one that should reduce
        $('#Box1').OuterWidth = ContainerWidth - $('#Box2').OuterWidth();
}
```

To add the ellipsis, I would reduce the width of `Box1` by a futher amount (~5px?) and programatically add in the `...`.

**Edit:** on the re-read of your question I realise that this is exactly what you have already done; but I will leave the code here for future searchers.